# Agent works on Dialogflow, but not on Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I don't know how to use Webhook or another language, so I am working with basic options of Dialogflow.
The problem is that my agent works on Dialogflow, but not on Actions on Google.

I made a list of google assistant. It has two options.
The one is "What is that?", and another is "Don't choose this".
I also add an event 'actions_intent_OPTION'. (This intent name is 'First'.)
And I want to allow users to input or choose only "What is that?".

If users input "What is that?", AI will say that "It's correct.".(This intent name is 'Second'.)
If users input another words or sentences except for "What is that?", AI will say that "It's wrong. Please send correct answer again."(This intent is Fallback Intent.).

For this, I made an entity of "What is that?" and I checked required option.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ufhU.png)
And by using contexts and Fallback intent, If users input another words or sentences, Fallback intent responds.The output context of Fallback is Second Intent.

First Intent's Input context: question /
First Intent's Output context: Answer (lifespan:1)

Second Intent's Input context: Answer /
Second Intent's Output context: Anotherquestion

Fallback intent's Input context: Answer /
Fallback intent's Output context: Answer (lifespan:1)

It works well on dialogflow.
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdJOu.png) [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR0wh.png)

However, It doesn't work on Actions on Google or mobile Google Assistant.
If I choose "What is that?", It says "It's wrong. Please send correct answer again."

I cannot find any problems.
Please help me.. ;(

Comment: I think.. input value is not be  stored on entity parameter

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the "First" and "Second" Intents?

Comment: I think it would be good if you update your question as it is not clear what exactly you try to do. Also as suggested above intent screenshots would be useful.